# How to make the character movement depends on a script i wrote it while the animator is on in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a character in unity which has an animator to make it animate ,
but i want it to be affected by the script which i wrote it, 
because i have two characters and i want to translate the movement from one to the other.
so the problem is that my character did not affect with my script while the animator is on.
I found some guys talking about it too[Override mecanim animation with manual bone rotation](https://answers.unity.com/questions/426741/override-mecanim-animation-with-manual-bone-rotati.html)
they was talking about to put your code in the Late update function but it did not work too.
So any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [OnAnimatorMove](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnAnimatorMove.html)? If you want to translate an object with Animator, this is another place where you can do your magic. It's behaves similarly to **Update** callback.